# Who first noticed violation of aufbau principle of elements like Cr, Cu, Pd, Au, and how?

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, experimental-physics, atomic-theory, nuclear-physics

It is often referred to as 'anomalous electron configurations' or 'unusual order of filling of orbitals' of a few elements e.g. Cr, Cu, Nb, Mo, Ru, Rh, Pd, Au etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle) clearly states :

> [n+l rule] was suggested by Charles Janet in 1928...Janet "adjusted" some of the actual n + ℓ values of the elements, since they did not accord with his energy ordering rule, and he considered that the discrepancies involved must have arisen from measurement errors. In the event, the actual values were correct and the n + ℓ energy ordering rule turned out to be an approximation rather than a perfect fit...

Comment: Thanks for your greeting (while writing the answer I thought I was in SE Physics!)... But I didn't ask the question, so why are you saying about the title to me?

Comment: My mistake. (+1)